# rails: how to link two ActiveRecords via Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got two models(Service, Profile), which have a has_many through relation with each other through a join table.

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :service_profiles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :profiles, :through => :service_profiles
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :service_profiles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, :through => :service_profiles
end

class ServiceProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

I created a Service and a Profile via CLI and now want to link those two via the Join Table. I would like to do something like this, but cannot find an answer:

```
2.6.3 :016 > profile = Profile.first 
  Profile Load (12.3ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Profile id: 1, name: "awesome Policy", description: "awesome Policy for awesome devices", created_at: "2020-05-26 08:56:08", updated_at: "2020-05-26 08:56:08">
2.6.3 :017 > profile.services.first.link
```

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html this is explained in the guides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your associations in the models are correct.

To join them in the database using the console, you can do something like this:

```
ServiceProfile.create(service: Service.first, profile: Profile.first)
```

or

```
profile = Profile.first 
profile.service_profiles.create(service: Service.first)
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I have been trying, but i had some syntax error. I just found this one, which works as well: service.profiles = [profile]