# How to create a has_many relation record in rails?`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a user model with some relations, and I want the user to be able to make Posts. So I set up a post model. The models are as shown below:

```
User.rb
belongs_to :plan

  has_one :profile

  has_many :posts

  has_many :follower_relationships, class_name: "Follow", foreign_key: "following_id"
  has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :following_relationships, class_name: "Follow", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :following, through: :following_relationships, source: :following

Post.rb
belongs_to :User
```

So my attempt to create a record:

```
def new
    @post = Post.new(user: current_user.id)
  end

  def create
    @post = @user.posts.create(post_params.merge(user_id: @user))

    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Post successfully created"
      redirect_to @post
    else
      flash[:danger] = @post.errors.messages.inspect
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

However, it returns the error `{:User=>["must exist"]}`. But the User does exist and is being passed in to the form.Then decided to try and create a post in the rails console.

```
 o = User.first.posts.build(image_url: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/188777/pexels-photo-188777.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940", title: "some", subtitle: "thing", body: "body")
o.save!
```

and it returned `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: User must exist)`

Why does rails think the user does not exist??

Comment: You can find an answer to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019390/rails-how-to-link-two-activerecords-via-join-table/62019903#62019903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `user` is a record, a `user_id` is an integer field. You're confusing them.

So this doesn't work...

```
@post = Post.new(user: current_user.id)
```

Instead do...

```
@post = Post.new(user_id: current_user.id)
```

or better...

```
@post = Post.new(user: current_user)
```

same goes for where you set `user_id: @user` ... you probably want `user_id: @user.id`